# Looking for device with following capabilities

Tags: tracking-devices

I'm looking for a device that has the following capabilities:

- min 50 Hz 3-axis accelerometer and 3-axis gyroscope
- bluetooth
- wifi
- programmable
- at least 1 Gb storage
- decent (rechargeable) battery (should be able to stream at least 20 hours of data)
- the smaller the better

I would be a plus, if it had any extra measuring capabilities (e.g. gps, temperature, magnetometer etc) had a sturdy casing and maybe a GSM module, but the main things are the ones I listed.

I've been looking around but haven't found one that could do all of these yet.

Comment: Which of the specs make it hard to fulfill?

Comment: I was hoping to :) Do you know something that is not much larger?  Actually, I'll edit the question and delete the actual size.

Comment: Could you add additional information about what are the expectations towards the device. Why do you need both Bluetooth and WiFi? Do you need data in real time, if yes do 1 Gb storage is really required?

Comment: It should be able to send the data to a smartphone (hence the bluetooth), be able to send data to a server without the phone (wifi) AND operate without a connection (hence the storage).

Answer (score 2):

Your best choice might be to have a look around on this [site](https://www.tindie.com/), quite a lot custom made hardware can be found here.

A partially appropriate one could be this [Tiny ESP32](https://www.tindie.com/products/kilobyte/tiny-esp32-board/?pt=ac_prod_search) board that is 29.21x26.72 mm, BT and WiFi capable programmable MCU with temperature, humidity and pressure on the board.

You can add a gyro and an accelerometer separately or you can use it as a reference for your own design in which you can add the additionally required sensors. There might be enough space for a small QFN gyro + accelerometer on that PCB.